# Enabling Automated Backups for Amazon DocumentDB Elastic Deployments

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

How can I enable automated backups and restore options for an Amazon DocumentDB elastic deployment? Instance-based deployments have built-in backup and restore capabilities, but I can't seem to find similar options for elastic deployments or any sign of an automated backup occuring.

Answer (score 0):

AWS support says automated backups are not currently supported. In the meantime I set up a bash script on a cron that performs a mongodump, zips it and stores it in an s3 bucket.